# unable to view jpeg file

Tags: python, jpeg, kaggle

I was trying to view a jpeg file using the codes that I found online.

Here is the codes:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np # linear algebra
import pandas as pd # data processing, CSV file I/O (e.g. pd.read_csv)

image = Image.open('/kaggle/input/chest-xray-pneumonia/chest_xray/__MACOSX/chest_xray/test/PNEUMONIA/._person121_bacteria_576.jpeg')
image.show()
```

But I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-637f422434fd> in <module>
     19 
     20 
---> 21 image = Image.open('/kaggle/input/chest-xray-pneumonia/chest_xray/__MACOSX/chest_xray/test/PNEUMONIA/._person121_bacteria_576.jpeg')
     22 image.show()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py in open(fp, mode)
   2685         warnings.warn(message)
   2686     raise IOError("cannot identify image file %r"
-> 2687                   % (filename if filename else fp))
   2688 
   2689 #

OSError: cannot identify image file '/kaggle/input/chest-xray-pneumonia/chest_xray/__MACOSX/chest_xray/test/PNEUMONIA/._person121_bacteria_576.jpeg'
```

I'm wondering if this is an issue because I didn't load the data or something else?
I wrote nothing else on the notebook on the Kagglenotebook with the dataset:  https://www.kaggle.com/paultimothymooney/chest-xray-pneumonia

Answer (score 0):

I usually name my files '.jpg' when using the PIL module and will then reference the appropriate file path.

I tried your code with a renamed **image.jpg** file and it worked fine, when I use '.jpeg' I get a similar error.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np # linear algebra
import pandas as pd # data processing, CSV file I/O (e.g. pd.read_csv)

image = Image.open('/Users/GameComputerC/ocr3.jpg')
image.show()
```

Let me know if it works for you. That might only be part of the error.

Comment: Yes, but the file is in Kaggle and there are quite a few of them. It will be time consumming to change the file names manually.